# Can I replace a power adapter of 1.5A with one of 1A?

Tags: power-supply

I have a Western Digital external hard drive that uses a power adapter to 12v and 1.5A, and it stopped working. I tried it with a tester and doesn't output any current at all.
Can I replace it with other adapter that is 1A? would that ruin the disk? would this work?

edit: The disk is a Western Digital 1TB ( model WDBACW0010HBK-01 )
http://wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=240
http://wdc.com/global/products/specs/?driveID=886

It doesn't seem to show anything about current requirements here.

* Moved from electronics: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25808/

Comment: check if the device is still under warranty western digital might replace the adapter for you. or at least you could get a compatible one from them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the amperage (A) of the power adapter must be equal or higher but not lower.

Comment: Safe and concise +1

Answer (score 7):

I do not reccommend doing so.

Just do the math:

```
12V * 1.5A = 18Watt
12V * 1A   = 12Watt
```

Your drive might run on 12 Watt, but I think that for starting up its peek is higher than that, maybe even higher than 18 Watt for a short time. (which can be compensated)

But even if it would be enough I would still not recommend it, you never know in which way an adaptor breaks down the frequencies and how clean the output is. An adaptor for charging up your mobiles batteries has other requirements than one for supplying a harddrive with very accurate currents.